# Can you increment/decrement over a TypeScript Enum to set the condition for a switch statement?

Tags: typescript, enums, switch-statement, react-typescript

TL;DR: Can you use a TypeScript enum to set a switch statement condition, using onClick functions to move up and down the enum, and keep the result constrained *within* that enum?

On a project, I needed to control which React component would display in a multi-level menu. The menu options were each objects fetched from an API, with some properties being arrays of other objects. For instance, on the first level, you would select a "Type", which would then return the second level populated with "Subtypes" associated with that "Type"; then you would click on the "Subtype" and you would get a list of "Subtype-Items," etc.

I was advised to use a switch statement to control this menu, and it worked. But I thought I could make it more efficient by using a [Typescript enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) to set the condition. Something like:

```
enum MenuLevel {
   TYPE,
   SUBTYPE,
   SUBTYPEITEM,
   ITEMOPTION
}

const displayLevel = (currentLevel: MenuLevel) => {
   switch (currentLevel) {
     case "TYPE": // or case 0:
       return <TypeMenu/>
     case "SUBTYPE":
       return <SubTypeMenu/>
   //  etc., etc., etc.,
```

You get the idea. My thinking went that since TypeScript enums - as long as you don't *initialize* them with strings - have numeric values for each, I could have a function like the following to automatically progress to the next level:

```
function progress(currentLevel: MenuLevel) {
  setCurrentLevel(currentLevel + 1); // CurrentLevel being set in state
}
```

I tried a few different ways about this. I tried passing `MenuLevel.1`, or `MenuLevel.TYPE`. I tried initializing it with numbers, but no matter what I did it wasn't passing what I needed to the switch statement. I concluded that I just didn't know enough about TypeScript enums to make this work and abandoned it, going back to simpler methods.

It still bugged me, though, and [so I experimented on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-junbmp?file=components/CurrentColor.tsx) to try and figure out if this was possible. I followed [this StackOverflow answer by jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63720348/3975739) as one example, but like my other experiments in this dev environment, it didn't work. I always get the number back, but it isn't constrained within the enum, which only has 3-4 members. It would even go into negative numbers if you decremented too much! Obviously that would end up breaking the switch statement and the `displayLevel()` function. So now I'm wondering, do I just lack proper understanding of enums, or is this truly impossible with them? Has anyone else tried anything like this?

Comment: I was explicit there that the result isn't constrained to the enum values and you'd have to handle that

Comment: Ah, okay, I misread your last comment. So constraining the result to the enum values *is* impossible, then?

Comment: It's not _impossible_, but you have to write code to do it - remember that's runtime behaviour, all of the types will be erased.

Comment: Ah, of course, of course. Duh, I should've remembered that the enum would cease to exist after transpiling. Ok, reading these comments and working over this, I think I'm understanding enums a lot better, including how to put the value into the switch statement. Need to experiment a bit more for myself, but I may have to find a way to credit you while self-answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know if this will be useful to anyone, but on the off chance it is, here is what I found from playing around with TypeScript enums. I think I found a way to use them for switch statements and control logic. (Examples below are in React using TypeScript.)

So, as **jonrsharpe** explicitly explained, incrementing or decrementing a number does not automatically constrain it to the values inside the enum. You have to provide control logic for that yourself. I also noticed, however, that it also did not work if you used a numeric array. Before we get to enums, consider the array case.

```js
export default function CurrentNumber() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as const;
  type OurNumber = typeof numbers[number];
  const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState<OurNumber>(numbers[0]);

  const min = numbers[0];
  const max = numbers[numbers.length - 1];

  function plusNum(currentNumber: OurNumber) {
    if (currentNumber < max) {
      let plusNumber = Number(currentNumber);
      plusNumber = plusNumber + 1;
      const newNumber: OurNumber = plusNumber as OurNumber;
      setCurrentNumber(newNumber);
    } else {
      console.error("Max number already reached");
    }
  }

  function minusNum(currentNumber: OurNumber) {
    if (currentNumber > min) {
      let minusNumber = Number(currentNumber);
      minusNumber = minusNumber - 1;
      const newNumber: OurNumber = minusNumber as OurNumber;
      setCurrentNumber(newNumber);
    } else {
      console.error("Min number already reached");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current Number is: {currentNumber}</p>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
        <button
          className="button is-primary"
          onClick={() => plusNum(currentNumber)}
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        <button
          className="button is-primary"
          onClick={() => minusNum(currentNumber)}
        >
          Decrement
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

We start by defining an array of numbers, and then we create a type from that array. ([I found out this was a thing by reading Steve Holgado's post.](https://steveholgado.com/typescript-types-from-arrays/)) We assert the array as `const` so it is not just the numbers but the values themselves (Holgado did this with an array of strings, it may be unnecessary for an array of numbers.) Creating this type, and then making our counter variable of this type, will keep us in bounds. With the `plusNum` and `minusNum` functions, we still have to check if the counter is at the min or max of our array. If its not and somewhere in between, then we  *have to convert it to a regular number*. Being `typeof OurNumber`, our `currentNumber` variable is actually `currentNumber: 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 5` -- being as it is an array, it's not even in proper order. (Or maybe my VS Code has a cold.) Adding or subtracting from it will throw an error. So, we use `Number(currentNumber)`, then do the math, then reconvert it back to `OurNumber`, and in React we use `setCurrentNumber` to set that in state. As you can see, I don't think this is terribly useful, and is probably a lot of extra work.

Now, on to a TypeScript enum, let's say we're using it to control the stages of a task or publication in production, and we have the following:

```js
enum ECurrentStage {
  "START" = 1,
  "MIDDLE" = 2,
  "FINAL" = 3,
  "REVIEW" = 4,
}

export default function CurrentStage() {
  const [CurrentStage, setCurrentStage] = useState<ECurrentStage>(
    ECurrentStage.START
  );

  function action(value: ECurrentStage, action: "increment" | "decrement") {
    switch (action) {
      case "increment":
        value++;
        if (value > 4) {
          return TypeError("currentStage is out of bounds");
        } else {
          setCurrentStage(value);
        }
        break;
      case "decrement":
        value--;
        if (value < 1) {
          return TypeError("currentStage is out of bounds");
        } else {
          setCurrentStage(value);
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current Stage Is: {ECurrentStage[CurrentStage]}</p>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
        <button
          className="button is-primary"
          onClick={() => action(CurrentStage, "increment")}
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        <button
          className="button is-primary"
          onClick={() => action(CurrentStage, "decrement")}
        >
          Decrement
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, we can increment or decrement the value directly. Here, `value` is the numeric portion of this enum. We still have to check if it is outside of our enum's bounds, and if so, throw some kind of `Error`. If not, we can then just set the `CurrentStage` state variable directly. Then, if we want the word and not the number -- which in my case is how the switch statement in my project was set up -- we use object bracket notation and set `ECurrentStage[CurrentStage]` and there we have it. In this example I'm just displaying it on a page, but this could easily go into `switch (ECurrentStage[CurrentStage]) {}` for managing logic elsewhere.

I'm really not sure if any of this is useful, but I didn't want my question to remain unanswered in case someone in the future has a similar idea and Google leads them here. These are definitely not the most efficient or elegant code examples either, and I'm certain they can be significantly improved upon. But hopefully this helps a future codeslinger implement their control logic more quickly and efficiently.