# how to expose properties of an enum via functions

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript and have been confronted with this scenario:

I want to expose some information about an enum like so:

```
const companyName: string = Company.apple.nameAsString()
```

This is to resemble a similar feature the Swift language has:

```
Swift
enum Company {
    case apple
    case honeywell

    func nameAsString() -> String {
      switch self {
      case .apple: return "Apple"
      case .honeywell: return "Honeywell"
      }
    }

    func tickerSymbolAsString() -> String {
      switch self {
      case .apple: return "APPL"
      case .honeywell: return "HON"
      }
  }
```

So far, I've implemented this:

```
export enum Company {
  apple = "Apple",
  honeywell = "Honeywell",
}

export namespace Company {
  export function nameAsString(company: Company): string {
    return company.toString();
  }

  export function tickerSymbolAsString(company: Company): string {
    switch (company) {
      case Company.apple:
        return "APPL";
      case Company.honeywell:
        return "HON";
    }
  }
}
```

I don't like this implementation because when using it, it feels too verbose:

```
      name: Company.nameAsString(Company.apple)
```

Is there a way to implement something that would allow me to do

```
const companyName: string = Company.apple.nameAsString()
```

Comment: I understand the desire for the swiftier syntax, but I think this is all typescript can do for you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28150739/1271826

Comment: Needless to say, the company name is not the problem (because you obviously can do `let companyName = Company.apple.toString();`), but rather the ticker symbol, where you are stuck with the more cumbersome syntax.