# Typescript: enum with functions

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following enum:

```
export enum ContentState {
    unstable = 'UNSTABLE',
    draft = 'DRAFT',
    stable = 'STABLE',
}
```

I want to check if a given `enum` within my program is `STABLE`. I want something like

`data.myState.isStable()`

and the check is done like `this===ContentState.stable`. I know I can do it within the code but I would be curious if I could spice up the enums.

I thought if I use as well

```
export namespace ContentState {
    const isReleasedStatus = (state: ContentState) => state === ContentState.STABLE;
}
```

but than I need to bypass the enum by itself. PLUS it is not imported into another class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add functions to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150739/add-functions-to-an-enum)

Comment: I found this as well. But the problem with the accepted answer is that it doesn't encapsulate the `enum` and the function in an own class - which can be done as proposed therein. The  general problem is that the function requires an argument with typeof `enum` whereas I am asking for NOT using bypassing it - more using it from 'within'.